# Isolated degenerate critical points

Tags: optimization, morse-theory

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ does not have any degenerate critical points on a set $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e. the Hessian of $f$ has full rank on  $S$). Is it possible to introduce a constraint $c(x)=0$ which limits the domain of $f$ to a subset of $S$ so that some critical point of $f$ becomes an isolated degenerate point?

Edit: $f$ is an analytic function.

Edit: Can add that I do not believe this is possible, and it would imply that isolated degenerate points only depend on the objective function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2+x^3$ with the constraint $x-y=0$?

Comment: You are right. Back to the drawing board, I guess